Delta Live Tables: How to reduce size of microbatch?
A delta live table pipeline reads a delta table on databricks. Is it possible to limit the size of microbatch during data transformation?
I am thinking about a solution used by spark structured streaming that enables control of batch size using:
.option("maxBytesPerTrigger", 104857600)
.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 100) 

Is any similar option applicable?

I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("dilip") \
    .config("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxBytesPerTrigger", "104857600") \
    .config("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxFilesPerTrigger", "100") \
    .getOrCreate()
    max_bytes_per_trigger = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxBytesPerTrigger")
max_files_per_trigger = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxFilesPerTrigger")
print(f"spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxBytesPerTrigger: {max_bytes_per_trigger}")
print(f"spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxFilesPerTrigger: {max_files_per_trigger}")    

Results:
spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxBytesPerTrigger: 104857600
spark.sql.streaming.fileSource.maxFilesPerTrigger: 100

Auto Loader processes a maximum of 1000 files per micro-batch by default.
You can adjust this by configuring cloudFiles.maxFilesPerTrigger and

cloudFiles.maxBytesPerTrigger

, which control how many files or bytes should be processed in each micro-batch.
The file limit is strict, while the byte limit is flexible, meaning more bytes can be processed than the specified maxBytesPerTrigger.
When both options are set, Auto Loader processes as many files as needed to reach one of the limits.
Reference: Configure Auto Loader for production workloads
